# NSInvalidArgumentException in didreceivelocalnotifiaction

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, mixpanel

I am bit bit confused as why am I geting this `NSInvalidArgumentException` error as I am not doing anything special.Here is my code do let me if I have done anything wrong.Basically i am implementing the the `Mixpanel analytics` in `didreceivelocalnotifiaction` and sending the fire time to the mixpanel.I have stored the value for username.Please let me know why am I getting this error.Moreover its not regular,it comes once in a while so that is making more difficult to find the error.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running

    Mixpanel *mixp = [Mixpanel sharedInstance];
    [mixp track:@"Notification Fired" properties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:notif.fireDate forKey:@"App Opens"]];
    mixp.nameTag = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Username"];
    [mixp identify:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Username"]];
}
```